# Working in Visual Studio Professional 2015 while updating to Update 3 - Visual Studio starts to fail

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I got the Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3 and launched the executable (vs2015.3.exe) while Visual Studio was still running. I got the following "Setup warning" but thought that a computer restart was fine as long as I could work during the update.

> Please close visual studio now to reduce the chance that a computer
>   restart will be required later

[image: Install]

Visual Studio immediately started acting strange, loosing Intellisense among others. I decided to restart Visual Studio and was then met with the error:

> Cannot run when setup is in progress

[image: Error]

I then canceled the update and thought that I could install this update during the night instead. When I opened Visual Studio again and tried to load a project I got the following error:

> Project '' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler
>   could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.

I then opened Update 3 executable again to complete the update. I was met with this feature list and could not do anything:

[image]

Restarted the computer but was met with the same dialog. I then opened Visual Studio again and this time the project loaded but without Intellisense. Restarted Visual Studio and now the project would not load at all. I then deleted the content of these 2 folders and ran `devenv /resetsettings`

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

I could now open the Visual Studio project normally again but I still could not get features when running the Update 3 executable. Is there anything else I can do or do I need to reinstall Visual Studio completely? I think it is really bad that the warning Microsoft gives is that a computer restart might be required when obviously the program cannot run in the background while updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by going to `Control panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Updates`. Click "Change" and then select "Repair".